# I can define a bang operator method, but I can't call it in Scala. Why?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

First I define `!` method:

```
scala> def !() = "hi"
$bang: ()java.lang.String
```

Now I can call it like so:

```
scala> $bang()
res3: java.lang.String = hi
```

But this doesnt' work:

```
scala> !()
<console>:8: error: value unary_! is not a member of Unit
              !()
```

Even this doesn't work:

```
scala> `!`()
<console>:8: error: value unary_! is not a member of Unit
              `!`()
              ^
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I allowed to define `!()` when I can't invoke it?

**EDIT1**

Adding an object reference gives error:

```
scala> this.!()
<console>:8: error: value ! is not a member of object $iw
              this.!()
                   ^
```

Comment: What happens when you leave off the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

```
!foo
```

is interpreted as

```
foo.unary_!
```

If you want to call your method, you must specify an explicit receiver, e.g.

```
this.!()
```

or

```
this !()
```

or

```
this ! ()
```

Comment: Inside the REPL `this.!()` and its variations dont work either. Please check EDIT1 in the question.

Comment: Inside the REPL, many things work differently. In this particular case, inside the REPL, `this` is the interpreter itself (or, more precisely, an interpreter workspace), so you obviously need to add the `!()` method to the interpreter object, if you want to call it this way.